# Unable to set Array as inputparameter to OracleCallableStatement from java

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, ojdbc

The oracle code :

```
PROCEDURE get_details (
        p_array     IN   XXX_TYPES,
        .....
        ......
    )
```

where XXX_TYPES is a complex type in Oracle:

```
    TYPE IDType
    IS
      RECORD
      (
        c_number           c_table.c_number%TYPE
        );
    
    TYPE XXX_TYPES
    IS
    TABLE OF IDType;
```

And the java code to set input Parameter :

```
//Create an array of Struct objects
Object[] array = new Object[] {"1", "2"};
OracleStruct createStruct1 = (OracleStruct) con.createStruct("IDType", array);
Struct[] structArray = new Struct[] {createStruct1};
OracleArray createOracleArray = (OracleArray)con.createOracleArray("XXX_TYPES",structArray);
            
//Set the input parameter
cs.setArray(1, createOracleArray);
```

Getting exception for OracleStruct createStruct1 = (OracleStruct) con.createStruct("IDType", array); line:
unexpected error - java.sql.SQLException: Inconsistent java and sql object types, for classes implementing ORAData or OracleData, respective factory classes ORADataFactory and OracleDataFactory should be registered in typeMap.

Looked SOF but most of them referred to [StructDescriptor](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/StructDescriptor.html) which is deprecated now.
appreciate any help on this or any link to setting and array as stored procedure input parameter would do.

Comment: Which version of the driver are you using?

Comment: ojdbc 8. got it wrkng by creating an OracleStructure with type and Object[] as attribute than creating OracleArray with type and OracleStructure[] from above. The code is something like this. it.List<String> elements = new ArrayList();
elements.add("1","2");
List<Object> oracleArrayObject = new ArrayList<>();
elements.forEach(e -> {
  oracleArrayObject.add(con.createStruct("Structure_TYPE_NAME",new Object[] {e}));
});
OracleArray createOracleArray = (OracleArray)con.createOracleArray("Array_TYPE_NAME",oracleArrayObject.toArray());
cs.setArray(1, createOracleArray);
cs.execute();